# How to include .ebextensions directory while deploying war file to AWS beanstalk through jenkins?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war

I am trying to deploy Spring boot application war through jenkins which contains ebextension configuration files.

However either beanstalk or jenkins ignoring exextension files and deploying earlier war without ebextension files. Job is not uploading latest source zip in the S3 bucket (I could see last uploaded zip with version 201 where as current version is 204).

I even tried uploading war through AWS UI console. I couldn't see '.ebextensions' directory at "/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/".

What steps I need go through to make sure I have valid ebextension configuration and placed in valid path.

Edit 1:
I wasn't aware that aws will remove ebextension configuration files after execution. But I don't see any related command execution log in '/var/log/cfn-init.log' file.

```
2017-05-12 14:42:30,946 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2017-05-13 12:15:58,540 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2017-05-13 12:15:58,554 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2017-05-13 12:15:58,554 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2017-05-13 12:15:58,554 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2017-05-13 12:15:58,557 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2017-05-13 12:16:00,702 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2017-05-13 12:16:00,719 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2017-05-13 12:16:00,719 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2017-05-13 12:16:00,720 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
```

Following is my configuration in .ebextension configuration

```
filebeat:
 "/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml":
     mode: "000755"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       filebeat.prospectors:
       - input_type: log
         paths:
           - "/var/log/tomcat8/*.log"
       output.logstash:
         hosts: ["10.0.0.149:5044"]

commands:
  1_command:
    command: "curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-5.2.0-x86_64.rpm"
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
  2_command:
    command: "rpm -ivh --replacepkgs filebeat-5.2.0-x86_64.rpm"
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
  3_command:
    command: "/etc/init.d/filebeat start"
```

Comment: I don't know why your latest version isn't deploying, but the `.ebextensions` folder is removed from the staging area after the config files are executed, but before your application is moved to its final location.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for pointing out that aws will remove ebextensions configuration files after execution. I do not see any execution log in cfn-init.log or any sign of file beat setup in the server.

Comment: If you look in `/var/log/eb-activity.log` you should see lines like `AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_3_appname/Command 1_command` when your commands were executed. Also, you first section should be `files:`, not `filebeat:`, and you should only indent one level at a time - YAML is very sensitive to whitespace.

Comment: Indentation and chaging from filebeat to files resolved the issue. Thanks a lot @brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first section should be `files:`, not `filebeat:`, and you should only indent one level at a time - YAML is very sensitive to whitespace.